# Vis Studio Build Tools 2017 MSBuild 15.4 /t:Restore

Tags: package, restore

I am using the VS Build Tools 2017 With MSBuild 15.4.8

The project builds and auto restores NewTosoft JSON pkg just fine in Vis Studio 2015 IDE. Not with the build tool however!

C:\Source\DevCopyJenkins\Utils\TestCIJenkinsNuGet>**MSBuild TestCIJenkinsNuGet.sln  /t:Restore**

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.4.8.50001 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 10/17/2017 11:14:14 AM.
Project "C:\Source\DevCopyJenkins\Utils\TestCIJenkinsNuGet\TestCIJenkinsNuGet.sln" on node 1 (Restore target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
**Restore:

Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.**
Done Building Project "C:\Source\DevCopyJenkins\Utils\TestCIJenkinsNuGet\TestCIJenkinsNuGet.sln" (Restore target(s)).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.37